# Load terminal configuration with my titles

Tags: gnome-terminal, window-title

I used **[instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/387313/568682)** to customize my terminal profile.
Renamed terminal titles.
I saved terminals with:

```
gnome-terminal --save-config=/tmp/term-cfg
```

I restored terminals with:

```
gnome-terminal --load-config=/tmp/term-cfg
```

All my titles was replaced with full directory path. So **[instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/387313/568682)** did not help me with title saving.
Can i do something to **save\restore** tab-titles?

Comment: i tried to use _gnome-terminal --tab --save-config=/tmp/term-cfg_ result was the same. saved config also was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i can not find correspond command to solve the problem.

So I created **[recommended script](https://askubuntu.com/a/310750/568682)**. This script has some problems but better than nothing. Before use script i need install **xdotool** with command.

```
apt-get install xdotool
```

to restore saved terminal i use:

```
gnome-terminal --load-config='my path to script'
```

But anyway i hope someone knows better solution... waiting for one.

**Update the answer**

First solution works without additional tools and scripts for some cases:
title should not contain some service symbols like **/**